# Using user input as parameter while running shell command in Ruby

Tags: ruby

When i pass name = a.txt, then `ls` should take a.txt as input and provide correct output.
This is not happening. Tried all possible combinations of quotes. I am a Ruby novice so plz excuse my naivety.

```
  puts "Enter name: "
  name = gets
  name.chomp!
  puts `ls  + name`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
puts `ls #{name}`
```

The `#{}` form can be used to insert the result of a ruby expression inside a string.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the interpreter that name is a variable and that you don't just want the string "name", but rather the result of interpreting the value, which you do via #{VAR_NAME}.

```
puts `ls #{name}`
```